# How can I check if mxArray has class type?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I need to compute the hash function of some variables inside mex function. Particularly I need to process a variable that is 24x1 [geopoint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geopoint-class.html) vector. To do this I need to check its class, because there could be any variables as input, so I compute it using `mxGetClassID`. However, `mxGetClassID` returns value 1437, which doesn't correspond to any documented value in [mxClassID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxclassid.html), neither it is `mxOBJECT_CLASS`, which could be reasonable. I've also tried `mxIsObject`, but it returns false.

I have implemented the hash function for arrays, structures and cell arrays, and they all need different processing, but I'm stuck with classes. So how can I check if the given variable is an object?

**UPD:**

If I run `mxGetClassName` function from mex or `class` function from MATLAB Command Window for that variable, they both return "geopoint", but there is no info whether it is an object or not.

The function code is below:

```
void appendMxArrayHash(const mxArray* array, uint64& hash) {
    mxClassID classID = mxGetClassID(array);

    char buf[100];
    sprintf(buf, "classID '%d' in appendMxArrayHash", classID);
    mexWarnMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:NotImplemented", buf);

    appendHash(classID, hash);
    switch (classID) {
        case mxINT8_CLASS:
        case mxUINT8_CLASS:
        case mxINT16_CLASS:
        case mxUINT16_CLASS:
        case mxINT32_CLASS:
        case mxUINT32_CLASS:
        case mxINT64_CLASS:
        case mxUINT64_CLASS:
        case mxSINGLE_CLASS:
        case mxDOUBLE_CLASS:

        case mxCHAR_CLASS:
        {
            int n = mxGetN(array);
            int m = mxGetM(array);
            void* data = mxGetData(array);
            int elementSize = mxGetElementSize(array);

            appendHash(n, hash);
            appendHash(m, hash);
            appendHash(n * m * elementSize, (char*)data, hash);
            break;
        }
        case mxCELL_CLASS:
        {
            int n = mxGetN(array);
            int m = mxGetM(array);

            appendHash(n, hash);
            appendHash(m, hash);
            for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++) {
                mxArray* cell = mxGetCell(array, i);
                appendMxArrayHash(cell, hash);
            }
            break;
        }
        case mxSTRUCT_CLASS:
        {
            int n = mxGetN(array);
            int m = mxGetM(array);
            int nFields = mxGetNumberOfFields(array);

            appendHash(n, hash);
            appendHash(m, hash);
            for (int i = 0; i < nFields; i++) {
                const char* name = mxGetFieldNameByNumber(array, i);
                int nameLength = strlen(name);
                appendHash(nameLength, hash);
                appendHash(nameLength, name, hash);
                for (int j = 0; j < n * m; j++) {
                    mxArray* field = mxGetFieldByNumber(array, j, i);
                    if (field)
                        appendMxArrayHash(field, hash);
                    else {
                        appendHash(0, hash);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            char buf[100];
            sprintf(buf, "Unsupported classID '%d' in appendMxArrayHash", classID);
            mexWarnMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:NotImplemented", buf);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD2:**

That is `array` variable looks like:

```
trackSegment = 

 24x1 geopoint vector with properties:

 Collection properties:
     Geometry: 'point'
     Metadata: [1x1 struct]
 Feature properties:
     Latitude: [1x24 double]
    Longitude: [1x24 double]
    Elevation: [1x24 double]
         Time: {1x24 cell}
```

Comment: Too much verbiage, too little (none) code.

Comment: What's the class of that variable reported as if you test from the MATLAB interactive command window?  How about from `mxGetClassName`

Comment: You are not trying to use Matlab objects in a C++ environment, are you?

Comment: @user3528438: That's the whole point of MEX

Comment: [`mxGetClassName`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetclassname.html) or [`mxIsClass`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxisclass.html)?

Comment: @horchler: `mxIsClass` is useless for discovering the type of a variable, since you have to specify the string form of the class and it merely confirms or denies.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't know why you'd say that. It perfectly useful if you want to check if a variable is an object of a particular class that you know and want to detect. It looks like the OP is trying to find objects that are geopoint class as far as I can tell – however, the OP's answer confuses me because all it checks is if an item is an object or not, which is not what the question appears to be about.

Comment: @horchler: He's dispatching to different hashing code depending on type.  So, short of calling `mxIsClass` a hundred times with all possible values of the class, he should be querying the class with `mxGetClassName`.  Like I said, `mxIsClass` can confirm the class if you already have an opinion about what it should be, but it cannot discover the class.

Comment: My guess is that geopoint is the first type he's come across causing problems.  If MATLAB `isobject` and `mxIsObject` give different results, and `mxGetClassID` returns an undocumented number, that would be reason to pay special attention to it..

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sorry about confusion with `geopoint` class. You're right that hashing should work with object of any class and `geopoint` is just an example. That's the reason why I need to check if the value is a class, or not.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally figured out how to check variable. For some reason there is no alternative to `isobject` in mex. `mxIsClass` doesn't fit because it requires class name, which is unknown, as was mentioned in comments. So I just used `mexCallMATLAB` to call `isobject`.

The code is rather ugly and not the most effecient, however it works:

```
mxArray* isobjectResult = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxLOGICAL_CLASS, mxREAL);
mexCallMATLAB(1, &isobjectResult, 1, const_cast<mxArray**>(&array), "isobject");
if (mxIsLogicalScalarTrue(isobjectResult)) {
    // process array ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you say the class name is unknown? You indicated in your question that you're dealing with geopoint objects, i.e., the class name is `'geopoint'`, as also reported by `mxGetClassName` (or Matlab's `class` function). Maybe what you're asking about and trying to do is not clear enough in your question?

Comment: @horchler: But geopoint objects are not the only type of object he has to handle.